# Google API v3 retrieving all contacts

Tags: java, google-api, google-contacts-api

I'm writing a code (in Java) that let me get all contacts from my google account, using google API v3. My problem is that after I successfully authorize access to account I get contacts only from "Most Contacted" group. As feedURL I'm using https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/default/full/ according to this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts). Basically my code is copy-paste of this example, so how can I get all my contacts?

Comment: can you share code ?

Answer (score 2):

In the documentation https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts there is a note saying "The feed may not contain all of the user's contacts, because there's a default limit on the number of results returned"
You can use query parameter to manage the information https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_contacts_using_query_parameters. Here you can find the parameters for these requests https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters.
The parameter max-results is probably the one you need.

Comment: Thanks for response. Unfortunately your solution doesn't work. I tried to get ContactFeed using Query with max result set to 9999, and all I've got was the same result (same amount of ContactFeed entries) as before :/

Comment: Could you add a code example? i tried it in the Oauth playground and it works for me, https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground check if you are missing something in the request.

Answer (score 0):

The correct parameter is **max-results**