# How to get Google Contacts in java application with normal authentication

Tags: java, google-contacts-api

I want to implement code for getting all Google Contacts in my application with normal username/password authentication (Without using OAuth2).

Right now for accessing google mails in my application  for that I am using two way for authentication.

1. for those users who have DNS disabled (application using with IP:port)basic username/password authentication with the help of "Allow less secure Apps: ON"
2. for those users who have DNS enabled, then using google Oauth2

So, Is there any way for getting all Contact details with  "Allow less secure Apps: ON" setting.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269848/google-api-v3-retrieving-all-contacts

Comment: Thanks Flavio, But here my concern is about authentication with Google. I am able to fetch contacts with OAuth protocol. But i want to know the way, when user want to login with plain username/password setting (Without Oauth token scenario).