# Fetch Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail contacts with pagination using OmniContacts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, gmail-api, yahoo-api, omnicontacts-gem

I'm using [OmniContacts](https://github.com/Diego81/omnicontacts) to integrate with Gmail, Yahoo, Hotmail APIs. But It's fetching all contacts of account. Some users have more than 1000 contacts.

So, I need to add pagination to send request to the API. In Gmail the gem has limit as this `importer :gmail, "xxx", "yyy", :max_results => 1000`. But I need to add pagination not limit.

How can I send request with pagination for Gmail API, and (Yahoo, Hotmail) APIs?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27269848/google-api-v3-retrieving-all-contacts) and [the docs here](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/reference#Parameters) are what you need

Comment: My Question to add pagination in the request to Gmail API. For example your account has 1000 contacts. I need to get them by 20 contacts per page. Like `Pagination gem` in rails. `http://example.com?page=1`. So, Can I use the `OmniContacts gem` with paginate ?